# Images shift position when page is zoomed

Tags: css, image, html, zooming

Here is the actual project (test page), as I'm having trouble recreating the issue:

http://benphilippi.com/ben-home-final.php

I have a series of linked images positioned over a background image, as 'buttons'.

When the page is zoomed, all the images shift. Worst is at 110%, by 125% it gets a bit better.

I've tried wrapping the divs in a container, removing divs altogether, and setting images as div backgrounds, but cant seem to fix this.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How much do they shift? Rounding issues?

Comment: They shift upwards between 5-10px when the page is zoomed to 110%:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dimensions are specified using the px unit. Try specifying your dimensions using the ex unit. This maps the size and position of everything according to the text size. As such your page should scale uniformly when the user zooms in and out.

Parenthetically speaking, I didn't notice any problem scaling the page in my browser. I'm using firefox on OS X.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try using ex, is there a conversion ratio for px to ex (i.e. 10px = ?ex)

Comment: @Perfect Dark & deau - I'm testing the page in Chrome.

Comment: Strange, the issue happens for me in Chrome, FF and IE. I'm running windows 7.

Comment: The ex unit is the height of the 'x' character on the element being styled. This can change depending on your font size and whether the user has zoomed the browser in or out.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Will update when I find the solution.

Comment: Using the ex unit definitely fixes this problem. Thanks deau!